# What sequence of GIT commands can reliably update a working directory to a specific branch/tag/commit of code?

Tags: git

I'm trying to do with GIT what I used to do in one line with SVN "checkout".

**What sequence of GIT commands can reliably update a working directory to a specific branch/tag/commit of code?**

These commands are executed in a Continuous Integration environment. I have a large number of third party dependencies imported via GIT, and they have a variety of branching and tagging strategies. The top-level repository is SVN, so GIT submodules is not a useful approach. From one build to the next, we may update to a newer version of a third party library, so we need to update our working folder. I run these commands on ubuntu and windows, orchestrated with bash and powershell respectively. The projects I'm building are mostly C++.

The information you have is

- A GIT repository (e.g. `git://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth.git`)
- A GIT reference, which may be *any of* a branch (e.g. `master`), tag (e.g. `osgearth-2.6`), or specific commit (e.g. `e42866faa3f042e942cfc707f78e9d0d99d64a45`), and you don't know in advance which of these things (branch/tag/commit) it is.

You would like to check out that version of the code into a working directory that may or may not exist. Also it may have previously been updated to track a different branch/tag/commit from the one you now want to track.

My best attempt is as follows. I've listed the git commands below for readability, the full powershell script is [here](https://gist.github.com/boinst/2af48067a3ac66a38629).

```
(if working directory exists) git fetch <repository> --tags
(if directory does not exist) git clone <repository> <destination>
git checkout <branch/tag/commit>
git merge "origin/<branch/tag/commit>"
git pull
```

- "Fetch --tags" seems to be necessary if I need to update to a newly created tag. I can't "checkout" a tag unless I have fetched it.
- "merge" seems to be necessary, because "fetch" didn't get all commits from "origin" for a branch that wasn't previously tracked.
- "pull" seems to be necessary to get the latest changes on a branch. It doesn't make sense to me that that would be the case, since "pull" is supposed to be "fetch" then "merge", but experimentally it does seem to be the case.
- This sequence of commands fails at the "git merge" step if the git reference is a specific commit. (error message is "merge: origin/b509a0cee255cdf55afe5cbd75be3944555b7332 - not something we can merge")

Comment: It sounds like you should use a real dependency management solution (NuGet in the .NET world, NPM in the node world, etc)

Comment: @DanielMann, yes, that would be nice. However, I'm working in C++, there's no widely accepted dependency management solution, and for good reason. Even if I had a dependency management solution, I'd still need to build the dependencies to push to the dependency management solution (unless I rely on others to do this for me), so my question would unfortunately and painfully still stand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: try `git checkout -f <ref>`. As @ChrisBeck correctly suggests it could be enough for your needs.

If it's not for some reasons, here's a complex solution for a "quasi-CI" system:

1. If you haven't `clone`d a required repository yet, clone it as a bare repository.
2. Set `core.bare` to `false` using e.g. `git config`.
3. Now you should use `git new-workdir <path/to/bare-repository> <a-new-directory> <ref>` to create a dedicated working directory for *each* requested build.
4. `git submodule init` & `git submodule update` if needed.

Thus you avoid problems with clashes between different versions of the code, avoid need of strange merges and other potentially fragile actions. Also build artifacts for different builds are kept in case one need them to cope with problems in the code. Probably you also need to organize some kind of "build rotation" completely removing build directories not being accessed for a while.

[`git-new-workdir`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir) is a script in the `contrib` directory. You need to copy/link it to `/usr/libexec/git-core/` (or whereever git internal utilities are located in your distribution) and make it executable.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved greatly by putting `git checkout -f <ref>` at the very first line, since that is what will work in most cases and it is quite simple. Then, put all the "if that fails..." stuff afterwards. Currently its much harder to get the useful information out of this answer than it should be.

Comment: `git-new-workdir` is a neat idea. It doesn't seem straightforward to configure gitcontrib on Windows, but I'll try that. One scenario where `git checkout -f <ref>` doesn't work, is where a new upstream tag has been created. In that case you need at least `git fetch --tags` before `git checkout -f`.

Comment: Yes, you're right that running complex shell scripts (`git-new-workdir` is a shell script, I added its URL to the answer) is a non-trivial thing. I'm updating the answer now.